# Is a connected sum of manifolds uniquely defined?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

It is a standard excercise in differential geometry to prove that a connected sum $M\#N$ of two smooth manifolds $M,N$ of the same dimension is uniquely defined (under some assumptions regarding orientation). In the proof one needs to show that $M\#N$ does not depend on:

1. the choice of balls (chart maps) around fixed points $(m,n)\in M\times N$ (assuming that maps in comparison induce the same local orientation near $m$ or $n$),
2. the choice of points.

I can prove the first for smooth manifolds (for two neighbourhoods of $m\in M$, I choose such a small neighbourhood that it looks like a ball in *both* charts, and I observe that the claim is trivial for balls). The second follows from homogeneity of both: topological and smooth manifolds.

**My question is:** Prove or disprove the first point for topological manifolds. If necessary, one can assume orientability, but the smooth case gives hope that the claim may be true also for non-orientable manifolds.

**Technical clarifications**: For the sake of this question "the" definition of $M\#N$ is as follows. Take $(m,n)\in M\times N$ and chart maps establishing homeo/diffeo of neighbourhoods of $m,n$ with open balls. Then canonically identify the punctured balls with cylinders and glue the cylinders reversing the vertical coordinate:
$$B\setminus \{m\} \simeq  S^{n-1}\times (0,1)\owns(s,t) \mapsto (s,1-t) \in S^{n-1}\times (0,1)  \simeq B'\setminus \{n\}.$$
To avoid problems we can assume that the chart maps can be extended to bigger balls.

---

P.S. <del>Some related doubts</del> **Update:** My earlier doubts resolved thanks to discussion in the comments:

- why wikipedia needs (note that the definition of connected sum in wiki is slightly different than mine):

  - oriented manifolds (in both cases if I understand correctly). **Resolved:** Thanks to George Lowther's comment I already know that the connected sum [depends](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_of_connected_sum_depends_on_choice_of_gluing_map) on the orientation of the spheres/cylinders glued (I missed that in my proof previously).
  - and why it mentions some "canonical glueing" as necessary for the uniqueness (in the smooth case)? **Resolved:** as studiosus states in the comments, the thing is that wikipedia allows ugly diffeomorphisms of spheres that can not be extended to the whole disk, which is not the case in this question,
- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) claims the answer is affirmative "crucially" by the [disc theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_theorem), however the [article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-02/S0002-9939-1960-0117741-0/home.html) cited handles the differential case.
  **Resolved:** The disc theorem is false for the topological case, because a sum of Alexander horned sphere and the bounded component of its complement is homeo with the disk, while the unbounded component is not homeo with complement of the unit disk in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Connected sum is not uniquely defined in the smooth category if you allow arbitrary diffeomorphisms of boundary spheres.

Comment: @studiosus In my definition there are no spheres, I have open disks extendable to bigger open disks. Is it not unique with this definition? My sketch of proof seems so legit...

Comment: The spheres are the boundary spheres of your disks.  Now, look at Milnor's construction of exotic spheres. They are all connected sums of 7-dimensional spheres!

Comment: @studiosus: As far as I can see in wikipedia, Milnor's construction is done via glueing the spheres. And I'm glueing the cylinders (I'm glueing $n$ dimensional objects while he is glueing $n-1$ dimensional ones). If you think it doesn't make any difference, could you elaborate?

Comment: It does not make a difference since a diffeomorphic map of $n-1$ spheres extends to product diffeomorphism of the $n$-dimensional annuli.

Comment: @studiosus: I'm still not fully convinced. In my definition we have a product diffeo (identity) of balls including your spheres, not just an annuli (very exceptional diffoemorphisms of spheres extend to product diffeomorphisms of balls - if I'm correct: 1) the derivative at 0 must be an orthogonal map and 2) assuming that it is the identity, we already know that the diffeo of our spheres is the identity). Anyway, do you know what are the "canonical diffeomorphisms" that are required to avoid problems?

Comment: In other words: I claim that if a diffeo of spheres $S^n\subseteq \mathbb R^{n+1}$ extends to a product (in polar coordinates) diffeomorphism of balls, then the extension is a linear orthogonal automorphism of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Can we require even more from the "canonical diffeomorphisms"?

Comment: If you assume that your gluing diffeomorphism of $S^n$'s extends to a diffeomorphism of $B^n$'s then the problem goes away and you get uniqueness of smooth connected sum.

Comment: @studiosus Of $B^{n+1}$s. Yes, I do - as it is written from the very first version of the question.

Comment: If you don't require the orientations to match up, then I am not sure that it is unique. I'd be interested to see a counterexample.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I'm not sure what you mean by matching orientations, but do you know an argument for uniqueness under this additional assumption? In wikipedia the definition is slightly different and they use a false argument (disc theorem for topological embeddings)...

Comment: Yes. I worked out my own proof using the Schoenflies theorem. A slightly simplified, but strong enough version of the Schoenflies theorem can be proved using a form of the Mazur swindle, which itself uses connected sums, but only very specific instances of them so there is no circularity. That is my own proof though - I don't know if there is a simpler standard proof.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Can you explain what exactly your assumption is? I can imagine that existence of orientation on $M,N$ might be helpful, but I don't get why we should match anything. Could you possibly sketch the proof in the answer? EDIT: Oh, now I see. An orientation-inconsistent connected sum may a priori be different from an orientation-consistent connected sum, right?

Comment: @saviki: Yes. Gluing the boundaries of the balls together could give a different result than reflecting one of them before gluing. In general, even if it does give the same result up to homeomorphism, it would require a global homeomorphism. Although it seems like the orientation should matter, I can't think of a specific example where it definitely does. Also, I can post a proof using the Schoenflies theorem, but its getting a bit late, so I have favourited this question and can come back tomorrow and post an answer if it hasn't already been answered by then.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther That would be great:) Now I realized that I didn't think about orientation in my sketch for the smooth case. But I think that I don't need an orientable manifold. It should be enough to assume that orientations induced by the two chart maps in comparison agree. P.S. savick, not saviki.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276763/can-i-flip-orientation-at-a-point-of-a-non-orientable-manifold) question suggests (there is no well-written answer) that for non-orientable manifolds the connected sum is uniquely defined (at least for the smooth case). On the other hand, [existence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/orientation-reversing-diffeomorphism) of manifolds that do not admit diffeomorphisms of degree $-1$ *could* lead to some counterexamples in the oriented case.

Comment: The connected sum of two complex projective planes depends on the orientation of the gluing maps: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Connected_sum_of_two_complex_projective_planes_with_same_orientation&oldid=3909

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Thanks! But that's really subtle, the (co)homology groups still agree, one needs to refer to the cohomology ring. Very interesting.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I think there is a mistake on subwiki. In the relations defining the cohomology ring the term $xy$ is missing, right?

Comment: @savick01: Maybe, it does look wrong (the rank is too large). Anyway, I just noticed a problem with the proof I was thinking of for uniqueness of connected sums, so I'm not so sure any more.

Comment: You can prove it from the annulus theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem), which looks like it could be difficult to prove. According to the history, it was proven in different dimensions decades apart. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I should have checked MO before asking... Thank you very much for all your help. Even though it is not covered in the MO question, I think that the annulus theorem enables the proof also in the non-orientable case, doesn't it? I think you should copy your comment to an answer.

Comment: Yes, in the non-orientable case you don't need to worry about aligning orientations at the join. Also, thinking about this myself a bit, you can consider a special class of manifolds - ones given by charts whose transition maps are stable homeomorphisms (in a local sense). You can prove that you get unique connected sums for these types of manifolds (as long as you match orientations at the joins). The annulus theorem then says that all homeomorphisms of $R^n$ are stable, so these manifolds are the same thing as plain old topological manifolds.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Would you like to write an answer, or should I do it in order not to leave the question unanswered? Btw. Do you know the answer to this related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/491023/18493)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: How can we take care about connected sum in smooth category? for example: probably we have more than one smooth structure in $M^8\sharp M^8$. Yes? If so, how can one guarantee that, that exotic structure on $\partial D^8$ is compatible (i.e. the obtained structure is smooth) with structure of ($D^8$ removed from) $M^8$?

Comment: @C.F.G: The structures on the boundary spheres are standard since the balls $D^n$ are supposed to be "coordinate balls," i.e. round balls contained in coordinate charts.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Is it in the definition of connected sum that "supposed"? If so why you say that it is not unique?

Comment: Yes, it is required. As for non uniqueness, it is the gluing diffeomorphism that is non unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write a self-answer to summarise findings from the comments (mainly by George Lowther).

An assumption previously missing in the question is the one regarding orientation. For non-orientable manifolds it is not important (due to that [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276763/can-i-flip-orientation-at-a-point-of-a-non-orientable-manifold) or a [characterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Topological_definitions) of non-orientable manifolds as containing $n$-dimensional equivalent of the Möbius strip), but if both manifolds are orientable and [do not admit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/orientation-reversing-diffeomorphism) an orientation-inversing automorphism, then depending on using chart maps consistent or inconsistent with the orientation we can obtain two [different](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_of_connected_sum_depends_on_choice_of_gluing_map) topological spaces.

The claim is true due to the [annulus theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnnulusTheorem.html) (rather [nontrivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem#History_of_proof)) - which enables a proof similar as in the smooth case. The theorem highly relies on the innocent assumption:

> "To avoid problems we can assume that the chart maps can be extended to bigger balls."

A very similar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds) was asked previously on MO.