# A connected sum and wild cells

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds

**Can we find such a connected sum of two spheres (in any dimension) that is not homeomorphic to the sphere?** $\def\R{\mathbb R}$

It seems that there should be examples like that, because there are lots of examples of "wild spheres" or "wild cells", the best known being the [Alexander horned sphere](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlexandersHornedSphere.html) (such a tricky embedding of a closed 3-ball [and its boundary sphere] in $\R^3$ that its complement is not homeomorphic to the complement of the standard unit ball - the fundamental group of this complement is not only nontrivial but also not finitely generated!). If we embed $\R^3$ in the sphere $S^3=\R^3\cup \{\infty\}$ then glueing complements of such objects (which are completely different from disks) should result in something not homeomorphic with the sphere.

However - surprise, surprise - [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1969804) from 1951 claims that two solid horned spheres glued via the identity map on the boundary are homeomorphic with the sphere...

**Update:** note that we need two "wild cells" to produce a counterexample - if only one embedding of disk to the sphere is nonstandard, then the operation of connected sum just fills this nonstandard hole to reconstruct the sphere.
Offtopic: even more is true in dimension $3$: the hole could be "cut" by a $2$-dimensional sphere (not necessarily being a $3$-disc!) and still by filling it with a disc we get the $3$-sphere as is cited in this [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-13/issue-2/The-sum-of-two-crumpled-cubes/10.1307/mmj/1028999538.full) (1st sentence of the third paragraph).

I suppose that an example may be nontrivial, but maybe someone here knows the reference.

Comment: I initially thought the answer was no by uniqueness of connected sum, but it turns out that result (at least as stated in Lee) relies on the balls you remove being "regular Euclidean balls", which e.g. the Horned sphere does not seem to be. (In retrospect the very existence of the article you linked should have made this trivial by some metamathematical deduction.) Interesting question.

Comment: At a brief glance this paper seems to be what you're looking for: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970180

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes, it is! Thank you very much:)